# AJAX Query into Rails with HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, api

I'm working with a pseudo API. I got a sample AJAX call from the developers, and am working to convert it into Ruby with [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to make a call from an object.

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonpCallback: "DataCallBack",
        url: "http://servicedomain.com/Widgets/Quotes.ashx",
        data: { partnerID: '39' }
     })
```

As of right now, my call looks like this:

```
query = {
  'dataType' => "jsonp",
  'crossDomain' => true,
  'jsonpCallback' => "DataCallBack",
  'url' => "http://servicedomain.com/Widgets/Quotes.ashx",
  'data' =>  { 'partnerID' => '39' }
}

HTTParty.post("http://servicedomain.com/Widgets/Quotes.ashx", :body => query)
```

The response is a web page that says the URL isn't valid. Is my syntax right?

Answer (score 1):

It's a `GET` request:

```
query = { 'partnerID' => '39' }

HTTParty.get("http://servicedomain.com/Widgets/Quotes.ashx", :query => query)
```